# Liberty profile + MQ Client + Security exit

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

In liberty, we are connecting to a MQ server.

We need to specify a "securityExit" on "jmsActivationSpec/properties.wmqJms".

Q: How to setup the jar that implements that security exit? We tried to put it in:

- wlp/lib
- wlp/dev/api/third-party
- servers/nom_server/lib/global
- shared/config/lib/global
- then add "classloader commonLibraryRef="global" in the "enterpriseApplication" tag

without success...

I have the feeling that we need to reference "global" from the "jmsActivationSpec" definition (similar to the "jdbcDriver libraryRef="global"" inside the dataSource tag) but ther is no tag for that

Everything works fine if we disable the security exit on the server side and do not specify the "securityExit" attribute in server.xml

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right.  The securityExit and securityExitInit (data) should be specified in the same property file as the channelName.

If you are using an MQ JNDI then it would be:

```
define qcf(qcfClient) qmgr(MY.QMGR) channel(TEST.CHL) hostname(MYHOSTNAME) port(1414) transport(CLIENT) SECEXIT(com.acme.security.Exit) SECEXITINIT(somedata)
```

Comment: ? I'm not using jndi, just using the "properties.wmqJms" tag in server.xml to set the values for the MQ connection, and this tag has a "securityExit" attribute to define it. This is done this way onf the WAS  full profile console, and the jar with the exit is deployed in the .../etc folder on the WAS machine

Comment: You can use it as a reference and note that you put the fully qualified class name in the value for the 'securityExit' tag.

Comment: This is what I do. This is not the question. The question is where to put the jar? Please read again my question. Now I got "classnotfoundexception" because the MQ connecter does not find the class specified in the securityExit attribute